# How to reduce the server log size in jetty

Tags: logging, size, jetty, reduce

I want to know how can I split the jetty server log when it reach to 10MB file size and backup while running?

I am using jetty 8 web server.

Thanks in advance.

Imesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Jesse for the reply but I did not try the way you mentioned. I resolved the problem in this way. Downloaded the jetty source and got the logging file named `RolloverFileOutputStream.java` then I changed the value `maxFileLenth` in the `RollTaskBySize()` method.

```
long maxFileLenth  = 1048576*10L;    //(10MB)
```

I put this file inside my source code and changed the value in jetty-loggin.xml.
Set the path to pick up the modified RolloverFileOutputStream.java from my project as below in bold.

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
<New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
  <Arg>
      <!-- ****** THIS IS THE CHANGE THAT I MADE ***** -->
      <New class="rezg.gdsws.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
      <Arg>
<Property name="jetty.logs" default="/var/log/rezg/app/jetty"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.Server.log
      </Arg>
      <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
      <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
      <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
      <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

Comment: Hi I couldn't find RollTaskBySize method in this class RolloverFileOutputStream

Comment: Hi vels4j, I can email you the class if you give your email address. As I do not see any place to attach the file here.

Comment: I sent the mail. Pls check and confirm. Better to check in spam box also.

Answer (score 1):

drop in an slf4j api jar into the lib directory and slf4j will be used for logging from that point on..put in the logging impl you want and configure accordingly

you can see the basic setup with logback doing the heavy lifting here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback

Comment: I'm having the same issue. need to limit error log file size. but couldn't get from your link. When I look the source code I am unable to find the method RollTaskBySize. Can you help. thanks